# Conga usage statistics

Tags: conga

I'm generating documents with custom button which leads to Conga composer. Is there any way I can get a statistics/report - how many documents were generated using this button, or using Conga in general?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, figured that out. Conga has own report "Recent Activity", in Conga Composer Setup, also there is "Activity logging" checkbox while generating a document - corresponding task is created in Salesforce.